# Best way to show alertbox before an activity finishes?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

I have an alertbox I use for showing errors.  It is in a general utility class that I can call from any activity.   When I call the error box, I pass the current activity along with the error message.

```
 Util.showAlert(this,"error message goes here");
```

My showAlert looks like this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("ERROR");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I ran into a recent problem and not sure the best way to fix this for this issue and any future ones calling the same generic alertbox.    My MainActivity calls a SecondActivity.   In the onCreate for that activity, I do some processing and then need to open a database and get some info.   If the info is not available, I can't run the SecondActivity and therefore must exit and return to the MainActivity.

In my error checking routine in the SecondActivity, I check to see if I have the data... if I do, I continue.  If not, I call:

```
 Util.showAlert(this,"Whoops, we have a problem");
 finish();
```

The problem is, the finish() fires and the SecondActivity closes BEFORE the showAlert opens.

Under normal circumstances with an error, I am still in that activity.  In this case, I am not.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: you should do the checks in the main activity and get rid of the ( finish();). its pointless to move to a 2nd activity and then check

Comment: Unfortunately can't do it in main activity.   There is some processing beforehand in the 2nd activity and that determines the success / fail when the database search fires.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, the finish() fires and the SecondActivity closes
>   BEFORE the showAlert opens.

Finish Activity after showing Alert or when user press `OK` button on AlertDialog by calling :

```
act.finish();
```

in `onClick` method of `AlertDialog` .

Comment: If I put the act.finish in the AlertDialog, it no longer is a universal portion of code that I can use in a variety of places, activities, and events when an error is needed to be shown.    The majority of them, the onClick wouldn't be associated with "finish" on a activity.

Comment: @Peter: then use `instanceof` for check if act is object of Activity then call finish otherwise do what u want

Answer (score 0):

You need change your logic in code show dialog, flow me
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();

```
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("ERROR");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            act.finish(); // act is Activity(context) showing Alert
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false) // cannot dismiss without Ok button
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

and in case Error you only call

```
 Util.showAlert(this,"Whoops, we have a problem");
```

Comment: The problem still is, this is a reuseable error alert.  In most cases, I won't want to FINISH the activity... but in some case, I will.  That is why I didn't put the FINISH in the onClick.